# Why don't we use silver hydroxide instead of Tollen's reagent for test of aldehydes?

Tags: reagents

AgNO3+NH4OH=AgOH+NH4NO3
AgOH is used for the reaction with aldehyde. But why can't we use silver hydroxide directly?

Comment: Silver hydroxide is not really a thing.

Comment: Silver hydroxide does not exist. Silver salts react with hydroxide ion to produce silver (I) oxide. See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75705/finding-ions-in-water-samples/75728?r=SearchResults#75728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silver hydroxide does not exist.

Hydroxides of alkalic metals form insoluble silver oxide:

$$\ce{ 2 Ag+ + 2 OH- -> Ag2O + H2O}$$

Ammonia  forms with silver ions the linear diammin complex, the nature of the Tollens reagent:

$$\ce{ Ag+ + 2 NH3 -> [Ag(NH3)2]+}$$